# execute a curl command throwing error 13 permission denied

Tags: android, curl

I am new to Andriod app development, I am trying to execute a curl command in Android Studio

```
:curl -X POST url(the url i am hitting) --user username:password .
```

This throws an error `stating permission denied error=13`, I tried executing this command through Eclipse and through command prompt, both of these works fine. Any idea why it throws an error in android studio?

Comment: how do you execute it in Android Studio?

Comment: if sCommand--> curl command
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(sCommand);

Comment: and then? I don't see the command. And also the question does not relate to ANdroid studio since this code will run on the Android device.

Comment: I am trying to trigger a build in Jenkins through Android: the curl command i used here is like: sCommand = "curl -X POST http://1*4.1**.1*4.**:8080/job/******** --user *****:******";

Comment: I have tried executing the same through commandPrompt/eclipse, it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

there is no `cURL` executable on Android.
You can use regular Android methods to do HTTP requests, like [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: I did the same using Http Connection. Thank you.